# Internal vs Unexported

Tags: go

What's the difference / use cases between using the `internal` package vs. not exporting? i.e.

```
package internal

type Foo struct{}
```

and

```
package bar

type foo struct{}
```

The only difference I can see is that with `internal` it would be easily possible to promote the package to public in  the future.

Answer (score 0):

The [export feature](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) determines whether an identifier can be accessed from another package. A non-exported identifier is not visible outside of the declaring package.

The [internal package feature](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU) restricts where a package can be imported.  An internal package cannot be imported from outside of the directory tree rooted at the parent of the `internal` directory.

The internal package feature allows a project to structure code into multiple packages without making the exported API of those packages visible outside of the project.  See the [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/) for more background on the motivation for the feature.